# Google pay not showing transaction I'd after paying google play console registration fee under subscription and services

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

8 hours ago my play console account was activated but I did not find my transaction I'd under subscription and services in pay.google.com
 I need it to transfer app from my friends console to mine..
But why suddenly Google not showing it.
Please help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. You should contact Google Play support. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: It there any solution you got? we are facing the same issue.

Comment: Hey, Check your email the ID starts with PDS.

Comment: google has changed the process now. if you need to transfer app then you can use this id sent to your email id starting with PDS . Hope this help. I just recently did it and worked

Comment: As all answers seems **out-dated,** you can have a look at [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53933896/2289835)

Comment: Rumit, That is what i told , you have posted in answer.